# Why doesn't the iOS status-bar network activity indicator show all activity?

Tags: ios, network, ui

I have noticed that the spinning network activity indicator doesn't always show up when I know it's using the network. For example, I have my iPhone SE and my iPad 2 both downloading iOS 9.3.2 right now. The icon shows on the iPad but not on the iPhone. And then when I start typing a question in Stack Exchange, the phone does show the network being used as it searches similar questions but when the search is done, the icon goes away even though the phone is still downloading over WiFi. Searching for tags, though, it does not show the indicator. What is the cause?

Comment: If you mean the two semi-circular arrows that spin, that's sync/backup activity, not network activity.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't mean that. I mean the little icon next to the wifi icon that looks like a loading circle.

Comment: [This one?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rcAuq.jpg) That's the sync icon. There is no 'network busy' icon, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Tetsujin No. If you don't know what I'm talking about try looking up iPhone network activity icon.

Comment: http://www.appfaction.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/spinning_iphone_wheel_nonstop.jpg

Comment: Ah, right, I got it, sorry. Never really paid it much attention before.

Comment: @kal-al If you wanted it to show all activity, it would basically never stop spinning, which wouldn't really be useful. Apple found a balance between informational and useful.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson An unpredictable circle isn't the ideal balance. How about any and all data more than 5KB in a second gets a little up or down arrow?

Comment: @kal-al I'm pretty sure that there is (or at least was) a jailbreak tweak that did that.

Comment: @kal-al The spinner is not unpredictable, though. Developers of iOS apps enable it when they feel that you need to know about some data being transferred. For example, in Twitter apps, the spinner appears when it's refreshing your feed. In an email client, it spins when it's grabbing new email for you. In Dropbox, it spins while it's uploading or downloading a file for you. But app developers might not need you to know about your game data being automatically uploaded to iCloud in the background, etc, so it wouldn't appear in that case and others like it.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that the visibility of *Network Activity Indicator* is managed by the App's Developer and not the System *detecting* a connection.

That being said, there are numerous reasons for this behaviours you're experiencing. Perhaps the Apps were coded to react differently to different actions, or they wrongly *hide* the *Network Activity Indicator* despite the fact a connection is being made.

Comment: That may explain things. It still confuses me though why even something like apps updating in the background might or might not show the network activity icon from the home screen. It would seem like it would make much more sense for Apple to make it a system-level indicator, maybe an up arrow if something is uploading and a down if downloading, that would be a lot more useful than some of the times knowing that something is happening.